# Unable to instantiate application class

Tags: android

> 8-03 11:35:19.736 5040-5043/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
>   08-03 11:35:19.863 16408-16408/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.app, PID: 16408
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.app: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.app" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.app-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5376)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.app" on path: DexPathList[[zip 
>                                                          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1014)
>                                                          at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5376) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1541) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) 
>   08-03 11:35:19.983 1490-1523/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied

Comment: Please share your class that extends from `Application`

Answer (score 1):

Solved above problem by disabling the instant Run[image]

Comment: instant run is disabled but is crashing again

Comment: Create Build using Top-bar in Android Studio > Build>Build APK(s).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem on more than one thread and it is almost always that the Application class name is absent, misspelled, misnamed, or in the wrong package in the manifest.

Double check your manifest and notice if the Application name is set and if it is green or red?  Your app will compile even if it is red--or indicating that there is an error.

BTW this happened to me with Instant Run disabled.  Instant Run is often named as the culprit when clearly the classloader cannot find the Application class, because of a name related problem.

Comment: Create Build using Top-bar in Android Studio > Build>Build APK(s).